# List all RHEL services without showing the PID associated with it

Tags: bash

I've been looking for a way to list all active services without showing the PID but I haven't had any luck so far. I've even been attempting to use sed to filter out the PID but still no luck. The end goal is a column of active service names only.

Example of desired output:

> auditd
>   crond
>   iptables
>   network

Here are a few commands I've been trying (I'm not real familiar with sed):

```
service --status-all | grep 'is running' | sort | sed -i \(.*\)
```

Output without piping to sed:

> auditd (pid 2097) is running...
>   crond  (pid 2859) is running...
>   iptables (pid 2548) is running...
>   network (pid 2159) is running...

It seems if I could exclude the (pid xxxx) then that would work but I'm not sure how to do that with sed. I don't get any output with the above command.

```
chkconfig --list | grep on | sed 's/\|/ /'|awk '{print $1}' | sort
```

The chkconfig output is what I want but it's not necessarily showing *active* services.

Comment: First off, wrong site to ask, secondly, show your attempts so far, thirdly, have you tried piping the output through either sed or awk?

Comment: If you want to debug your sed solution, then please post your command and its output, and then this question will be more on-topic and of reasonable scope.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've edited my post to contain more information.

Comment: This works. I'm not sure how to label your comment as the answer though.

Comment: @Ric I'm absolutely fine with you turning my comment into your own answer.

Comment: @Kamil Macriorowski Thanks. Wasn't sure how to do it. Still fairly new to the site. Wanted to make sure you got credit though.

Comment: @Ric I believe a good answer *should explain the code*, my comment didn't. At the moment I had no time, so I made a comment just to help you; this was deliberate so don't worry about any credit I may have lost. Also [read this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7181/432690). I think your cumbersome (yet noble) efforts to give me credits in your answer might be the reason it got a downvote – that's why I edited it. The site is about answers, they should be the best possible for users with similar problems. With my comment I left the door open for somebody to write a good, explanatory answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
service --status-all | grep 'is running' | cut -f 1 -d " "
```